# iOS In-House Distribution does not work with Amazon S3 Storage

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, in-house-distribution

I recently was able to setup In-House Distribution for the company I work for. It works great.

One thing that we had to do in order to get this to work was we had to actually store the manifest.plist and Program.ipa on the server filesystem. Previously, our site would store the files in Amazon S3 storage.

The URL path for the file looked like this when it was stored in Amazon S3:

- /Builds/DownloadInstall?loc=Installs/iOS/1.0.131/Program.ipa
- /Builds/DownloadInstall?loc=Installs/iOS/1.0.131/manifest.plist

When it is stored on the filesystem it looks more like this:

- /Builds/InHouseDev/Program.ipa
- /Builds/InHouseDev/manifest.plist

Both ways, the manifest was configured properly for the relative URLs, however when we used the links for the file locations in Amazon S3, nothing would happen when you tapped on the link to install the in-house dev build.

Does anyone know what could be happening here?

Thanks for any help,

Answer (score 0):

The install files have to be physically on the server for this to work. I don't know the technical reason why.. I think it has something to do with the way the side-loading works with iOS.